# How to get single Observable by parameter in angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am trying to use `switchMap` combined with template `async` pipe so I think I need to return an `Observable`. But this is just not working.

```
this.route.params.switchMap( (params: Params) => 
  this.course = this.courseService.get(params['id'])
);
```

I thought in the template

```
<div *ngif="course | async as c">
  {{c.name}}
</div>
```

should subscribe this observable and trigger the request to server but it seems not. What did I misunderstand here? The same approach seems ok with `ngFor` on `Observable` array.

Fixed this by, ( still confusing what switchMap does here, I steal it from somewhere):

```
this.route.params.subscribe( params => this.course = this.courseService.get(params['id']));
```

Anyone can explain, why switchMap not working in this case.

In my other project, this works:

```
this.route.params
      .switchMap((params: Params) => 
         this.journalService.getJournal(+params['id']))
      .subscribe( (journal) => {
        this.journal = journal;
      });
```

Comment: Is route.params subscribed?

Comment: that's the thing. I defined this.course as Observable and I used rsync pipe in the template. Do I still need to subscribe? how?

Comment: I think this.route.params might also need to be subscribed, if it is not subscribed, the code inside switchMap won't run at all. You can try to add .subscribe() after switchMap. And I don't understand what you are using switchMap for.

Comment: Your question is helpful. I got it work by subscribing params. Maybe you can answer about when to use params.subscribe and when to use params.switchMap? This is my confusion here, still. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the `switchMap`.

`switchMap` expects to receive an observable but you're not returning an observable: `this.course = this.courseService.get(params['id'])`.

You might try that instead:

```
this.course$ = this.route.params
  .map(params => params['id'])
  .switchMap(id => this.courseService.get(id));
```

And

```
<div *ngIf="course$ | async as c">
  {{c.name}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [blog](http://blog.angular-university.io/functional-reactive-programming-for-angular-2-developers-rxjs-and-observables/) maybe helpful for you. According to this blog:

> #### Observables are either hot or cold
>
> If this plain Observable has no subscribers, it will not be triggered! 
>   The observable is said to be cold because it does not generate new values if no subscriptions exist.

`switchMap` is a operator which is supposed to be used to transform data coming from stream. You can learn all rxjs concepts on its [official site](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html).

> Operators: are pure functions that enable a functional programming style of dealing with collections with operations like map, filter, concat, flatMap, etc.

Hope that can do some help.